# Why do molecules showing a pure rotational spectra require a permanent dipole?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, dipole, electromagnetic-radiation

I understand that pure rotational spectra only exist for molecules which have a permanent dipole moment.  The common explanation is "so that they can interact with the **E**-field of the incoming photons", but I don't think it is clear why photons can only interact with dipoles.

I'm also aware that the answer probably has something to do with the matrix element $\langle\psi_i|x|\psi_j\rangle$ where $\psi_i$ and $\psi_j$ are the initial and final states of the molecule, and $x$ comes from the dipole moment operator.  I'm just not sure why we need *this* matrix element and not something else.  And as an extension, why does Raman spectroscopy depend on the polarisability of a molecule, whose operator behaves like $x^2$?

Comment: In semi-classical terms think of the the electromagnetic wave (ir /microwave , visible uv etc)  as an oscillating electric field, this can interact with the oscillating electric field of a rotating molecule caused by its permanent dipole, hence dependence on $x$. When the energies are the same, i.e. in resonance, energy can be absorbed from the EM wave into the molecule and _vice versa_.  Raman is scattering, the polarisability is a volume, $x^2$ is due to the cross section (area) seen by the radiation.

Comment: The matrix element for rotational spectra comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule. The relevant Hamiltonian is proportional to $\hat{x}$, hence your expression. (Well, I think it is $\propto \hat{x}$ as long as you define your coordinate system carefully; but in free space, we have the freedom to do that.) Not sure about Raman, though.